# Changing font size of hidden cells

Tags: vba, excel

To make a long story short, I have an excel with a lot of filter options. To accommodate some different screen sizes I made a macro that changes the column widths and font size.

```
Sub SmallMode()

'
'Change to Small Mode
'font size to 9, various cell widths, Small Mode title
'

Range("B2:Z200").Font.Size = 9
Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 10.86
Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 10.71
Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 33.14
Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 21.86
Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 8.71
Columns("M").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("N").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("O").ColumnWidth = 10.57
Columns("S").ColumnWidth = 7.43
Columns("T").ColumnWidth = 5.86
Columns("V").ColumnWidth = 12
Columns("W").ColumnWidth = 7.14
Columns("X").ColumnWidth = 11.43
Columns("Y").ColumnWidth = 14.29
Columns("Z").ColumnWidth = 15.71
Range("Y1").Value = "Small   Mode"

End Sub
```

my problem with it is that while the widths work great, the font only resizes the current cells, not the ones that are hidden under a filter. Is there a way to force all of them into the right size?

Comment: Why don't you apply the font size before filtering?

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why you need to change anything on a hidden cell.

Comment: it is an overview of all of the orders in my department. I have several buttons that filters the ordertypes into subcategories. So if I have a list with orders, one button shows only orders of subtype A and hides B & C, another shows B and hides A &C etcetra. so they are hidden at that moment, but if you switch departments its a mess of different font sizes in the same list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**, to handle hidden columns also

you can unhide all cells, apply font formatting and finally hide back previously hidden cells

like follows

```
Dim visibleCells As Range
With Range("B2:Z200")
    Set visibleCells = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide all rows
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'unhide all rows
    .Font.Size = 9
    .EntireRow.Hidden = True
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End With
With visibleCells
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With 

Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 10.86 
....
```

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect

Comment: in my test it does have effect!  You may want to show your scenario in more detail

Comment: aahh ok i found the difference i think. there are hidden columns, not rows. But if I change the EntireRow to EntireColumn it still does not work

Comment: see edited answer. you have to both keep `EntireRow` and add `EntireColumn` handling. if it solves your question please mark it as accepted. thank you